# Проект Qt собирается, но не запускается

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw

Собрал проект Qt, но при попытке запуска из Qt Creator в консоли сборки следующие сообщения:

```
11:55:38: Выполняются этапы для проекта MiniAMR...
11:55:38: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
11:55:38: Запускается: «C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe» 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'X:/build-MiniAMR-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'X:/build-MiniAMR-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'

11:55:41: Процесс «C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe» завершился успешно.
11:55:41: Прошло времени: 00:03.
```

Как избавиться от подобной проблемы?

Comment: Это абсолютно нормальные сообщения об этапах компиляции, линковки и сборки исполняемого файла

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что мне необходимо было в директорию `'X:/build-MiniAMR-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'` подложить одну .dll-ку, которую я сделал накануне.

Вопрос закрываю, проблема решена, но так и не понятно почему именно в этом была проблема.

Comment: >>но так и не понятно почему именно в этом была проблема<< Статическая ссылка/линковка?

Comment: Потому что, видимо, ваше приложение подключает и использует данную библиотеку. Вы думаете qt хочет линковать то, что ему не заказывали? Оно ему надо? :)